# KQL shown count of the percentage

Tags: kql

I have a table of

TenantID    ....

A
A
B
B
C

I want summarize the percentage of TenantID  for each tenant. The expected output is:

A 0.4

B 0.4

C 0.2

How can I WRITE A KQL query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
let T = datatable(id:string) ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"]
;
let total_records = toscalar(T | count)
;
T
| summarize count() by id
| project id,
          percentage = count_ / total_records
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni! It works! What if I wand to add a where statement, like only include a and b? In your code, I need to add where into `total_records = toscalar(T | count)` and also the query below that. Is there a way to only write  where once?

Comment: just include it in the definition of `T`, e.g. `let T = ... | where <condition>;`